# How to fail a TestFixtureSetup in NUnit

Tags: c#, nunit, integration-testing

I'm currently writing some integration tests in NUnit that require some setup that is being done inside of a `[TestFixtureSetUp]` method. In the event that something goes wrong during setup (e.g. could not connect to the server), what's the proper way to fail the method and convey that to NUnit? Would I just throw an exception, or is there a specific NUnit method to call?

Comment: You can call `Assert()` inside `TestFixtureSeUp`, so if you need to make sure a connection was successful, you could just cal `Assert.IsTrue(myObject.IsConnected)` or whatever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the methods your calling throw exceptions on failure then just let them do that and the NUnit runner will catch them and fail the fixture unit tests.
- If you have a condition that should trigger a failure use an `Assert()` (like all your other tests)
- Otherwise, you can explicitly call the NUnit utility method
  [`Assert.Fail(message)`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=utilityAsserts&r=2.4.8).

  Most `Assert` methods allow you to define a message that will help you
  quickly diagnose the cause.

You might also find this [ShoudBe](https://github.com/tohagan/ShouldBe) NUnit wrapper library useful that will simplify and type check your assertions (replacing them with `<expr>.ShouldBeXXX()` fluent extension methods) and removing the need to write failure messages (it reports the expression that failed by reading your source code) + really useful enumeration messages. Because it's just a layer on top of NUnit, you can use it with your existing NUnit tools like Reshaper, NUnit Runner and CI. You can also safely add new ShouldBe unit tests to an old NUnit test suite or combine it with NUnit features like [parameterised unit tests](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=parameterizedTests&r=2.5).

Comment: Assert does work in a TestFixtureSetUp, but for some reason if the Assert has a Message parameter, the message is not displayed. The Test Explorer window simply contains "Message: TextFixtureSetUp failed in MyTestClass". I'd be interested to know if anyone has a solution for this.